# Como utilizar el TimesTamp en sql server

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, necesito tener un campo identificador con un `timestamp`, para tener un control de a que hora y cuando se realizaron modificaciones a esa tabla, pero al momento de crearlo me tira un error(

> Defaults cannot be created on columns of data type timestamp

), como puedo implementarlo de manera correcta.

```
 create table lista(
    id  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    nombre char(50),
    );
```

Comment: En corto, no se puede. El valor de [Timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms182776(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) es automáticamente generado por el motor de sqlserver. Si quieres insertar un timestamp manualmente, deberás utilizar DateTime, ~~como mencionó Yussef~~.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres guardar la fecha y la hora debes usar `datetime`

```
 create table lista(
    id  datetime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    nombre char(50),
    );
```

Por otro lado `Timestamp` es sinónimo de `rowversion` y en la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) señala:

> El tipo de datos rowversion es solo un número incremental y no
> conserva una fecha ni una hora

Adicionalmente tambien inica que:

> La sintaxis de la `timestamp` está en desuso. Esta característica se
> quitará en una versión futura de Microsoft SQL Server. Evite usar esta
> característica en nuevos trabajos de desarrollo y planee modificar las
> aplicaciones que actualmente usan esta característica.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Yussef , lo que quería lograr es que en cuanto se agregue un registro nuevo, en la fila de ID en automático se ponga un dato que yo pueda convertir en fecha y hora de cuando fue insertado. Por eso quería utilizar TIMESTAMP porque tenia entendido que funcionaba para eso.

Comment: EL tipo de dato `TIMESTAMP` tiene un nombre incorrecto porque no guarda fecha y hora. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` sí regresa la fecha y hora actual y funciona igual que `GETDATE()` pero existe para compatibilidad con el estándar SQL.